# Android Listview animations that don't suck

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I was looking here. http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/listview-and-listactivity-layout.html

It... sucks. One at at time? Also where can I find some cooler effects? Google is giving me that page like 6 times on 6 sites. Hurray for SEO .

Comment: I feel bad as i think this starts to look retro.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. Android ListView animations are a far cry from the slickness of UITableView in iOS. The entire architecture of Android seems to fight you at every turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can

- rotate
- translate
- scale
- change alpha

with animations. And combine in with the many different interpolators to define the speed and acceleration of an animation.

Here are [the main animation docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html).

Some people also developped some fancier animations by combining them like a [3d flip](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html). But it is always based on the elementary bricks enumerated above.

Comment: Nerd alarm: That's actually not quite correct. Those are just affine transformations. The 3D flip you mentioned is a projective transformation and cannot be done with those. Animations allow you to do much more than those 4 things (to be exact, all kinds of linear transformations in 4D space)

Comment: Would you mind to point out some reference for that ?

Comment: In the end it boils down to the Transformation class, and the Matrix it contains (which is actually just 3D, not 4D). Everything else is just Math (see Wikipedia for "Transformation Matrix"). The Matrix class itself contains methods for several 2D transformations like the ones you mentioned, while the android.graphics.Camera class helps you with 3D transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from android 3.0, you can animate just about anything that's visible with the property animator. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html) out.